# Get Objective-C enum value in swift

Tags: swift, objective-c, enums

I am new to swift and I am trying to solve the following problem.

I have a framework, that I use in my application.
The framework has multiple enums defined in Objective-C like this:

```swift
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, AdvertType) {
    AdvertTypeLoading,
    AdvertTypeFinished
    ...
};
```

I have a variable `eventState` with a string like "finished" and need to get the correct ENUM reference automatically.
For this I have tried the following code, but I keep getting an error, that `AdvertType` has no member `allCases`.

```swift
    for type in AdvertType.allCases {
        if type.state.caseInsensitiveCompare(eventState) == .orderedSame {
            return type;
        }
    }
```

Why does my ENUM not have `allCases` and is there any other way, how I can translate my string into the actual enum value, that I can used in a AdvertType typed method?

Is there maybe an easier way like?

```
let eventState = 'loading';

let enumState = AdvertType[eventState];

// should return AdvertType.loading
```

Comment: What is `type.state`? I assume this is a property you declared for `AdvertType` but didn't show in the question?

Answer (score 2):

`CaseIterable` is a protocol from Swift that allows you to use `allCases` property to access all types in the enum as a collection, so there is no way to Objective-c enum can conform it. You have to work around with this.

Approach 1, define a swift enum which mapping 1-1 with `AdvertType`. Then declare a property to return same type as in Objective-C or write an extension from Swift to manually implement `allCases` property. Thanks @Alex for pointing out to me:

```swift
enum Advert: String, CaseIterable {
    case loading
    case finished

    var enumAdapter: AdvertType {
        switch self {
        case .loading:
            return AdvertType.loading
        case .finished:
            return AdvertType.finished
        }
    }
}

if let loadingState = Advert(rawValue: "loading") {
    //TODO:
}

extension AdvertType {
    public static var allCases: [AdvertType] = [
        .loading,
        ...
    ]
}
```

<del>Approach 2, every time you want to get Objective-C `AdvertType` run a for loop to get the value with condition like you did above `type.state...` However, changing rawValue from String to UInt ("loading" -> 0) because the enum is defined NSUInteger.</del>

Edited for approach 2: my mistake was that I didn't look at `type.state` condition, it's also inside `AdvertType`. So, with String input parameter and UInt as initialization enum parameter, there is no way to convert such a easy way like you did in example above. If I were you, I would create a helper function to convert between them (I prefer approach 1). However, be aware of TYPO and return type in unexpected cases:

```swift
static func getAdvertType(from state: String) -> AdvertType? {
    switch state {
    case "loading":
        return .loading
    case "finished":
        return .finished
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. Would you mind providing a bit more details for example 2? Unfortunately number 1 will not work, because the enum in the lib might change and I need our Code to still work dynamically with changes without having to change it in my enum-copy every time.

Comment: @SimonEritsch I edited the answer, there was a mistake here. Unfortunately, there is no such a way to convert them directly.

Comment: You can add an extension to CaseIterable manually in an extension: `extension AdvertType: CaseIterable { static var allCases: [AdvertType] = [...] }`